# The pod has been stuck in the pending state for more than five minutes

Tags: php, mysql, openshift, openshift-nextgen

Hello I new to openshift online . Tried to deploy mysql pod and got this Error n command line

```
error: update acceptor rejected mysql-8: pods for deployment "mysql-8" took longer than 600 seconds to become ready
```

MY pod has an orange circle around it with a warning  saying :

```
The pod has been stuck in the pending state for more than five minutes.
```

I dont know what causes so. Recently i executed queries in my php to created tables in this database and to insert some data. could that be the cause? And if so How can i deal with it? thank you so much

I would be greatful if someone gave me steps of how to solve this

Comment: you may want to add the output of `oc describe <your pod> -n <your namespace>`